# Is there a list of charities that accept Bitcoin donations?

Tags: charity

Say someone wanted to donate some of their Bitcoins for charity, is there some comprehensive list of charities that accept donations in Bitcoins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most comprehensive list I can find is here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Donation-accepting_organizations_and_projects

There is also a website "Bitcoin-Charity" which converts BTC to $ on behalf of charities, promising not to put more than 1% towards admin costs. A neat feature of this site is that no technological knowledge is required by the charity to receive donations, and the total donated to date is listed (though it would be better shown in $ than BTC, or both). They currently have 9 charities listed: www.bitcoin-charity.com/charities/

Edit note: bitcoin-charities.com is no longer active.