# BTC for political donations?

Tags: economic-theory, legal

When I am asked to make donations, I assure the requester that I will donate if they accept BTC.  Initially, that gets a blank look, but I wonder how it might change if more of us took that approach.  Specifically, has anyone had success with making donations, political, religious or otherwise, using BTC?

Comment: related: [Is there a list of charities that accept Bitcoin donations?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2560/5406)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a number of [organizations and projects that accept Bitcoin donations](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Donation-accepting_organizations_and_projects).

The above linked list includes political parties (e.g. Libertarian Party in the US), at least one church ([St. John's in Goshen, NY](http://www.coindesk.com/saint-johns-becomes-worlds-first-catholic-church-accept-bitcoin-donations/)), a score of open-source projects, as well as a number of charities and other causes.